# Jenkins subversion tagging plugin - with yes/no option?

Tags: svn, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I've installed subversion tagging plugin, which works as expected but i do not want to tag every successful build but only tag release candidates. How to control this ? Is there a Yes/No that can be incorporated with subversion tagging plugin on Jenkins ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Select the build you want from the build history, click "Tag this build" from the list of links on the left. This is in-built functionality that has nothing to do with subversion tagging plugin.

[image]

Comment: You need to setup the template when you configure Jenkins. Once it's done, the tag will be setup more or less how you want it. When you do tag, it shows you the build that was tagged with a little floppy disk icon.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion tagging plugin donesn't have that feature. However you can achieve this in the following way.

1. No need to tag via subversion tagging plugin.
2. Use some script like the following which will tag the sources.

> rel=yes
>
> svn_tag_path=http://mysvn.com/svn/repo/tag/
>
> if [ $rel = yes ];then
>
> echo "Tagging the release Candidate";
>
> svn copy $WORKSPACE $svn_tag_path/$JOB_NAME_$BUILD_ID  -m "Tagging the release candidate from revision $SVN_REVISION"
>
> fi

set the value of the variable `rel` in the script to `no` or `something` for normal builds. For release candidates make the value as `yes`.

Comment: What does this script give you? Is this something you run in Jenkins during the build process? The tagging plugin is easier to setup. Besides, the OP stated they didn't want to tag _all_ builds. The _tag this build_ icon is the better way to go. You select what you want to tag via the build, and Jenkins does it for you. Plus, it puts a tiny icon showing you which builds were tagged.